# Are there any details regarding Polly's death?

Tags: plot-explanation, i-am-the-pretty-thing

In *I Am The Pretty Thing That Lives in the House* (2016), everything is laid out in the first few minutes.

The main character will die at some point, and there is a ghost named "Polly".

There is a back-story to the house: The builder of the house supposedly made it for his fiancee, and they both disappeared the night before/after marrying.

I assume Polly is the aforementioned fiancee.
There are some strange scenes depicting Polly happily walking around blindfolded, and

> Apparently she is killed and hidden in the wall, presumably by the builder, her fiancee. She appears to realize she is doomed when she sees him.

Is there any backstory released? Any director/writer interviews?
All I can find are reviews that either despise or love the movie, no one seems to know anything about it.

It appears to be veiled in mystery, but almost nothing happens, and there appears to be almost "nothing to it".

Are there any additional details regarding Polly's death?

Answer (score 1):

Polly was playing an early 19th-century game, probably a variation of hide and seek. Nineteenth-century parlor games were weird by today's standards and some of them involved blindfolds. As for her murder, that was more than obvious: it was right there before you. Watch it again. The groom smacks her with an ax and then walls her up. So he's an ax murderer, or a jealous husband, whatever. End of that story. It's all we need to know.

Comment: You're correct that the fact she was playing some kind of game is obvious, and that she gets killed by a guy with an axe and gets put into the wall is obvious too. I'm looking for some kind of motive.

Comment: @GorchestopherH maybe if your mind can accommodate the fact that killing or even attempting to kill someone, especially a girl, is an act either of diseased minds or an extremely stressed out, psychologically, one to have clarity in thought to analyze the outcome of the act. 

In the perspective of a play or a movie, it is important to establish the genre at which the script is targeted for, say, if it is for a detective thriller then the motive becomes the most important element in the plot and the whole script revolves around it.

Comment: @user2347763 What we know is pretty basic. Girl gets killed and put in the wall. I'm just asking if there's any more to it than that. To me, the big reveal at the end seemed empty, was hoping there was more to know. If there isn't, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think what she is asking is why did the husband kill Polly. If you remember he isn’t some mysterious man that just happened to axe her to death. Polly is the bride that disappeared. She does appear to be playing a version of hide-and-seem. Presumably looking for her new husband, but as she runs her hands against the wall she comes to an open space in the wall and cuts her finger. She removes the blindfold to find that the boards on the wall have been removed and she in return looks at her husband in confusion. I guess when she looks back at the hole in the wall She realizes what is about to happen. Right after that he hits her in the head and boards her body up in the wall. I’m guessing with the story that was told he then “disappeared” or left, leaving Polly’s corpse to rot. As for the motivation behind the murder, I’m not exactly sure why he would kill her. Something I noticed though is that when Polly first looks at him, he seems almost upset or on the verge of tears. Maybe he was just crazy. I’m not quite sure.